# Null Pointer Exception on Compilation time in android layout.xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I am getting Null pointer Exception when I use Custom widget type in my layout. I have that widget in my src file as well but can not find why this exception comes.

it gives following error on Compile time for **com.siliconithub.android.zoom.ImageZoomView**:

**java.lang.NullPointerException**

**Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log**

Here is my item_image_detail.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:minWidth="320dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="#000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <com.siliconithub.android.zoom.ImageZoomView
        android:id="@+id/imgWithZoom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/rowOptionsImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_bottom"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalLikes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_btnlike"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_like" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalComments"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_comment"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />
</TableRow>
```

What could be the reason?

**EDIT :**

Here is a logcat of it:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.siliconithub.android.zoom.ImageZoomView.onLayout(ImageZoomView.java:166)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1617)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1401)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:449)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:326)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1638)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1389)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1163)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:674)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:290)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2746)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1433)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Code of ImageZoomView :

```
public class ImageZoomView extends View implements Observer {

    /** Paint object used when drawing bitmap. */
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

    /** Rectangle used (and re-used) for cropping source image. */
    private final Rect mRectSrc = new Rect();

    /** Rectangle used (and re-used) for specifying drawing area on canvas. */
    private final Rect mRectDst = new Rect();

    /** Object holding aspect quotient */
    private final AspectQuotient mAspectQuotient = new AspectQuotient();

    /** The bitmap that we're zooming in, and drawing on the screen. */
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    /** State of the zoom. */
    private ZoomState mState;

    // Public methods

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public ImageZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Set image bitmap
     * 
     * @param bitmap The bitmap to view and zoom into
     */
    public void setImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;

        mAspectQuotient.updateAspectQuotient(getWidth(), getHeight(), mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap
            .getHeight());
        mAspectQuotient.notifyObservers();

        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Set object holding the zoom state that should be used
     * 
     * @param state The zoom state
     */
    public void setZoomState(ZoomState state) {
        if (mState != null) {
            mState.deleteObserver(this);
        }

        mState = state;
        mState.addObserver(this);

        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Gets reference to object holding aspect quotient
     * 
     * @return Object holding aspect quotient
     */
    public AspectQuotient getAspectQuotient() {
        return mAspectQuotient;
    }

    // Superclass overrides

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mBitmap != null && mState != null) {
            final float aspectQuotient = mAspectQuotient.get();

            final int viewWidth = getWidth();
            final int viewHeight = getHeight();
            final int bitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
            final int bitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();

            final float panX = mState.getPanX();
            final float panY = mState.getPanY();
            final float zoomX = mState.getZoomX(aspectQuotient) * viewWidth / bitmapWidth;
            final float zoomY = mState.getZoomY(aspectQuotient) * viewHeight / bitmapHeight;

            // Setup source and destination rectangles
            mRectSrc.left = (int)(panX * bitmapWidth - viewWidth / (zoomX * 2));
            mRectSrc.top = (int)(panY * bitmapHeight - viewHeight / (zoomY * 2));
            mRectSrc.right = (int)(mRectSrc.left + viewWidth / zoomX);
            mRectSrc.bottom = (int)(mRectSrc.top + viewHeight / zoomY);
            mRectDst.left = getLeft();
            mRectDst.top = getTop();
            mRectDst.right = getRight();
            mRectDst.bottom = getBottom();

            // Adjust source rectangle so that it fits within the source image.
            if (mRectSrc.left < 0) {
                mRectDst.left += -mRectSrc.left * zoomX;
                mRectSrc.left = 0;
            }
            if (mRectSrc.right > bitmapWidth) {
                mRectDst.right -= (mRectSrc.right - bitmapWidth) * zoomX;
                mRectSrc.right = bitmapWidth;
            }
            if (mRectSrc.top < 0) {
                mRectDst.top += -mRectSrc.top * zoomY;
                mRectSrc.top = 0;
            }
            if (mRectSrc.bottom > bitmapHeight) {
                mRectDst.bottom -= (mRectSrc.bottom - bitmapHeight) * zoomY;
                mRectSrc.bottom = bitmapHeight;
            }

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mRectSrc, mRectDst, mPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)     {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        mAspectQuotient.updateAspectQuotient(right - left, bottom - top, mBitmap.getWidth(),
                mBitmap.getHeight());
        mAspectQuotient.notifyObservers();
    }

    // implements Observer
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with logcat. see my edit portion.

Comment: I would start with line 166 in ImageZoomView.java. `java.lang.NullPointerException    
at com.siliconithub.android.zoom.ImageZoomView.onLayout(ImageZoomView.java:166)`

Comment: Can you post the code of the function contains line 166 of your ImageZoomView? The error comes from there

Comment: Now I have updated answer with code also...

Comment: It appears `mBitmap` or `mAspectQuotient` is null. What is line 166 and have you used your debugger to see which variable is null?

Comment: but it gives me compilation error, not at run time error.

Comment: When this happens, are trying to see your custom view in the "Graphical Layout"? I don't understand why it is trying to execute UI code while compiling...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing constructors:

```
/**
 * Constructors
 */


public ImageZoomView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ImageZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ImageZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyles) {
    super(context, attrs, defaultSytles);
}
```